# Entity Framework Int Data Not Getting Saved

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, mediator

I am working on .net core 7.0 api project with entity framework core, code first migrations. In this I have used Mediator Design Pattern. I have defined some entities which are inheriting some abstract class for base entities like below fields:

- CreatedDate CreatedBy ModifiedDate ModifiedBy

Now when I am trying to seed or save data, all fields inside the entities i.e. Name, Description are saved except those which are inherited from abstract class i.e. the above fields.
Can any one please suggest were I am going wrong. Below is the sample of my code structure.

```
 public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseAuditableEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public DateTime Created { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);

    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }

    public int LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
}

 public class Category : BaseAuditableEntity
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
}
```

DB Context code

```
public class DataContext : DbContext, IApplicationDbContext{
    public DbSet<Category> Category => Set<Category>();
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the classes shown.  Did you create your migration before you added the inheritance from Category to BaseAuditableEntity?  Did you run an additional migration and update your database after making that change?

Comment: Can you show how you are preparing your DbContext? Also, the `Id` property should have the `[PrimaryKey]` attribute decoration, so EF will update that when you save your entity into the database.

Comment: @ajawad987 my DBContext code i have added above

Comment: @NeilW, currently i have not run any migrations yet. I am using InMemorydatabase